# reload javascript class, ( Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of let 'classname' )

Tags: javascript, reload

I've tried to reload a javascript class file and get the following console feedback:

> 'Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of let Test'

```
<button id="reload">loadScript</button>

<script>

    let reloadBtn = document.getElementById('reload');
    reloadBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        
        let addonScripts = document.getElementById('js').querySelectorAll('.addon-script');
        
        addonScripts.forEach(function(s){
            s.remove();
        });
        
        loadScript('test.class.js', 'addon-script', function(){ console.log('script loaded'); });
    });
    
    
    
    
    function loadScript(url, styleClass, callback){

        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.classList.add(styleClass);

        if(script.readyState){  //IE
            script.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    script.readyState == "complete"){
                    script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    callback();
                }
            };
        } else {  //Others
            script.onload = function(){
                callback();
            };
        }

        script.src = url;
        document.getElementById("js").appendChild(script);
    }
    
    
</script>
<div id="js"></div>
```

test.class.js

class Test{

```
sayHello(){
    return 'hello';
}
```

}

```
let _test = new Test();
```

console.log(_test.sayHello());

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Reloading the script runs its code again, so the line `let _test = ...` will run a second time, and produce the error. What are you trying to achieve here? Why do you want to reload a script? That shouldn't be necessary in the first place.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your feedback! - that is exactly what it should do, it should run again after reloading. I have a lot dynamic content that needs the reload... but I don't really understand the ''Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of let Test' error...

Comment: There's no much to understand, it's simply not allowed: https://jsfiddle.net/aw0L752e/ Can't you simply reload the entire page instead?

Comment: no, its a panel system - it loads php incl. the scripts via ajax, without reloading the whole programm.

I know what you mean - but I remove the var with the script here: with s.remove();
And the Error Msg sais let Test not let _test - so there seems to be a problem with the class redeclaration.. maybe a memory thing..!?

Comment: I get the same error when I comment that out:
//let _test = new Test();
//console.log(_test.sayHello());

Comment: Right, the class is also redeclared, which is also not allowed. You need to isolate the code that you need to rerun, move it to a function and simply run the function again, instead of reloading the entire script. It is a memory thing in the sense that removing a script doesn't also clear the respective parts of the browser's memory, all the variables and classes are kept in memory.

Comment: That helped me. Thanks!!! Grüße nach München.